# Can Japanese voice actors watch anime for free after an anime episode is finished?

Tags: voice-acting, japan

Can Japanese voice actors watch an anime episode for free after an anime episode is finished because they did contribute their efforts in it?

Comment: i don't know but i would figure it's something similar to any games development (which seiyuu are hired for aswell) in which they see a very different product from what the public see, for example a rough version of it as shown in in the NSFW Spoilers in [this answer on hentai voice recording](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/41653/1587)

Comment: Please, no "hentai" allowed. I would like a fresh and reasonable answer (♡).

Comment: hentai is anime as well and it's reasonable to assume what answer this question has might also apply to hentai as well

Comment: Well, anime is Japan is basically free on TV and legal online streaming (or internet TV)...

Comment: Maybe you should change the question into do they get a free copy (DVD or BR) of the anime?

Answer (score 1):

Voice actors usually only see the parts of the anime/movie and script, which they record. Their might be special occasions, when they are able to see the complete episode, but that is definitely rare.

Comment: Although what you mention might be true in a general case, it'd be nice if you could also provide some references.

Comment: I used my knowledge to answer this question, because it is something, which I knew. Sadly I am not able to provide references for everything, that I know. But then again, if I would be able to do that, I probably would only know half as much as I do now.

Comment: The "additional references" from the SITE on this answer is bull <_<

Answer (score 0):

Voice Actors get paid. That is their compensation. And per se, voice actors aren't cheap. To specifically give them only the episodes they appeared in seems to be too much of a hassle. Just think how many side roles there can be in an episode.

That aside, occasionally special voice actors (main roles or special guests) can get gifts from the company they work for. E.g. the German voice actor Gronkh received a "LEGO Batman" Joker plushie for his work of speaking the Joker in the German Translation of the movie, ADDITIONALLY to his payment.

OP asks if watching the episode for free is something NORMAL Japanese voice actor get FOR their work. I say no, because Japanese have a special attitude towards their work. Being allowed to work for your company is something to be honored in Japan, almost as important as getting the money. If a company is especially grateful towards an actor, they may bestow him with additional honor. But that would be something of emotional value, not an episode of their own production everyone can buy. (At most, something like the first item of a collectors edition, and that's more of a gift for the producer. Voice actors would get something tied to their person or the role they spoke.) In addition Japanese are very polite, so it seems out of place to ask for free episodes if one really wants some.

And finally, it is work. Who has worked for a time, knows it is not always your wish to revisit your past work.